# How can an npm module provide its own Flow libdef out of the box?

Tags: flowtype

I've written an npm module with Flow type annotations. Its .flowconfig file includes `unsafe.enable_getters_and_setters=true` because it uses getters and setters internally.

But the problem with that is anyone who depends on my module (and uses Flow themselves) is required to set the same option to avoid Flow complaining about *my* module when they type-check *their* project.

What I want to do (and what I'm hoping is possible) is to provide a libdef file out-of-the-box, and have this take precedence over my source code, so any dependent's Flow will only look at my libdef and will not look at my code and complain about the use of getters/setters.

Can someone explain how to do this? My guess would be that I'm supposed to create a `.js.flow` file corresponding with any `.js` file, and publish this with my module, and this would then take precedence and prevent Flow from looking in the original `.js` file. (And maybe it should be possible to even generate my `.js.flow` libdef file automatically..?) But I can't find any information on this.

The docs site is great, but it doesn't seem to explain how to do this. The single [mention](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/#declaring-a-module-a-classtoc-idtoc-declaring-a-module-hreftoc-declaring-a-modulea) of the `.js.flow` file extension is a link to a JS `alert('TODO')` :)

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what you've describe. As you say the documentation on this is not yet up-to-speed. Did you manage to get it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type your package and publish them here: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed. Using the flow-typed tool, you can generate a full stub for your package and then fill out the types.

Alternatively, if your package's main is say `index.js` and contains all your exports - you can create an `index.js.flow` and define types for all your exports there.

Comment: Hi Lewis.  You say "Using the flow-typed tool, you can generate a full stub for your package and then fill out the types" - I'm looking for documentation on how to do just that but not finding it.  Any pointers please?

Comment: @ETFairfax it seems like this experience is still being improved, but currently: install your node_module into a package and then run `flow-typed create-stub your_module_name`.